# Bash Run command for certain time?

Tags: bash, time, timeout

I am making a bash script for my own use. How can I run a command for a certain time (like 20 seconds) and then terminate it? I have tried a lot of solutions but nothing works. I also tried the `timeout` command with no success. Please give me some solution for this.

For example: I want to run this command in a script and terminate it after 10 seconds

```
some command
```

Comment: The same question asked on https://superuser.com/questions/593006/bash-run-command-for-certain-time

Comment: "I also tried the 'timeout' command with no success" -- please post the command that you tried and the behavior that you saw.

Answer (score 15):

Hm, that should do the trick:

```
xmessage "Hello World" &
pidsave=$!
sleep 10; kill $pidsave
```

`xmessage` provides a quick test case here (in your case the airodump command should go there); `&` puts it into background.

`$!` holds the PID of the last started process (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1822042/2037712); the PID gets saved into the variable `pidsave`.

After some waiting (`sleep`), send a `TERM` signal to the process.

Comment: Thanks buddy it works but Now I have 1 problem.
I want to see output which is created by command but xmessage windows doesn't show anything.

Comment: @UmairRiaz: xmessage was just an example. To adapt your example in the question and log the output of the command use `some command > logfile &` in the first line. Afterwards you can analyse `logfile`.

Answer (score 4):

From the bash prompt you can use"

- `your_command & sleep 20; kill $!`
- Or use the timeout command: E.g. `aptget install timeout` and `timeout -k 3m 14s your_command`
- Or use `expect` as explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/how-to-introduce-timeout-for-shell-scripting
- or do it with perl: `perl -e "alarm 10; exec @ARGV" "Your_command"`
- Or use this more cryptic solution: `$COMMAND 2>&1 >/dev/null & WPID=$!; sleep $TIMEOUT && kill $! & KPID=$!; wait $WPID` (
  <sup>[Source and explanation](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3592/execute-a-command-with-a-timeout)</sup>)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use pgrep $pattern, or pkill $pattern;
returns all the PIDs matching the given pattern, looking across all running processes on the machine.
So to limit the scope of PIDs to only the ones you own, use:
pgrep -P $mypid $pattern, or pkill -P$mypid $pattern

So to run a background process for a set length of time, your script would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
mypid=$$
run_something &
sleep $time_in_seconds
pkill -P $mypid something
```

Keep in mind that this will kill all processes with the same name pattern running under the current parent PID. So you could use this to start multiple processes, and kill them all simultaneously after a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a command-line alarm clock like [ebay-alarm](https://github.com/kanliot/ebay-alarm)

Install the alarm clock script and do

`ebay-alarm 10 sec -c some command &`