# Run a script with bash and supply a termination time

Tags: bash

Is it possible to run a script from bash (e.g. python) with a termination time, meaning that if this script runs for longer than X seconds, terminate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to run a bash script with a timeout for it's termination. You can do it by :

#### 1. Using **[timeout](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html)** :

It runs a command with a time limit. General syntax includes :

```
timeout signal duration command/script arguments
```

where :

- signal is Signal name or corresponding number. See **[man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)**
- Duration is Timeout specified in numbers with suffix as **`s`** for seconds , **`m`** for minutes , **`h`** for hours , **`d`** for days.
- Default is seconds, When you only specify just a number. As an example say you want to terminate your script after 2 minutes, then :

  ```
  timeout 2m /path/to/script arg1 arg2
  ```
- `NOTE` : Default timeout signal is **`SIGTERM`** for which some processes does not terminate. In that case we need to use **`SIGKILL`** signal to kill the process.

  ```
      timeout -s KILL 2m /path/to/script arg1 arg2
  ```

  OR

  ```
      timeout -k 30 2m /path/to/slow-command arg1 arg2
  ```

  In this case, timeout first sends the `SIGTERM` signal after initial timeout of 2 minutes. Then, waits for another timeout of 30 seconds and sends a `SIGKILL` to the process if it’s still running.

#### 2. I [don't have `timeout`](https://superuser.com/a/664938/814740) command :

Well, There are many alternatives or workarounds, If for some reason you are unable to use `timeout`. These are :

1. Condition `sleep` then `kill` :

   ```
      /path/to/script arg1 arg2 & sleep 2m ; kill $!
   ```
2. Perl Alarms (This can be used within a sequential script.) :

   ```
      perl -e "alarm 120; exec @ARGV" "/path/to/script arg1 arg2"
   ```
3. Using [expect](http://fibrevillage.com/sysadmin/36-expect-command-examples-in-linux) command :

   ```
      time_out=120
      command="/path/to/script arg1 arg2"

      expect -c " set echo \"-noecho\";
                  set timeout $time_out;
                  spawn -noecho $command;
                  expect timeout { exit 1 } eof { exit 0 } "
   ```

Feel free to add-in more details.